# Is it possible to export WPScan results in excel file making it as an excel report?

Tags: python, wordpress

I am running a python script which performs a vulnerability scanning using the WPScan tool and the results are saved as a txt file localy.

Using that txt file I am not able to play with the results and crosscheck the with other scanning results, so for this reason I want to save that results in an excel file.

I have tried to find out a way inside the TXT file, if specific characters are used to define specific vulnerabilities types so as to help me in order to detect specific issues and add them to the appropriate column inside excel file.

I am not sure if there is a solution for this!

Comment: I'd suggest posting a question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) asking how to parse and iterate over items in a text file to convert it to a CSV/XLS

Comment: My suggestion would be to use python and regex to search for specific keywords within the report, use these as columns and their corresponding values as row items, and write them to a CSV/XLS report of your creation. It seems WPScan does not support anything other than TXT at the moment; see [this](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/issues/703) Github issue